# What influences indicator style of users in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Since learning to use different user profiles in Google Chrome almost three years ago, I've always thought the user representation is the avatar icon on the left corner. This is the case of the vast majority of (Windows) computers I operate.

[image]

Except for one particular Windows 8 laptop. Instead of an icon at the left corner, it displays a user name label at the right corner.

[image]

I cannot find anything that influences this difference in UI display. Is there something "special" about this computer that causes Chrome to behave/display differently?

Comment: First pic is how Chrome previously used to indicate user profiles. The latter is the new style

Comment: And that cannot be controlled? How is that throughout all the version updates, the ones with the old style still remain so?

Comment: @Ramhound what i mean is the other computers _all_ still display the "old" style despite a year's worth of updates. If Google is to change the style it strikes me as odd these continue to remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Profile switching UI is currently being revamped, the first picture that you see is the old profile system. The second picture is the new profile system.

The new profile system is not yet live, and Google is known to A/B test UI changes via Chrome [Experimental flags](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

In this case, disabling the *New Avatar Menu* found under `chrome://flags/#enable-new-avatar-menu` and disabling the new Profile Management found under `chrome://flags/#enable-new-profile-management` should result in you getting the old profile back.

But bear in mind that this is only till Google is testing the feature, once it's Live, then you cannot switch it

Comment: I disabled both options but the UI remains the same.

Comment: No, it appears it was not enough to simply close Chrome and restart it. Had to hit the "relaunch now" button for the changes to take effect. The old UI style is rendered now.